# Qt's QScreen refreshRateChanged signal doesn't fire on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

The program I am making in Qt is sensitive to changes in refresh rate of the monitor. I need to know which monitor my window is in and what refresh rate that monitor is because if the window goes full screen it's refresh rate goes to whatever the refresh rate of that monitor is (otherwise it just sticks to whatever the refresh rate of the primary monitor is).The original idea was to just query the current QScreen the window is in via the *screen()* method whenever the window was going full screen and check its refresh rate, along with connecting to QGuiApplication's *primaryScreenChanged()* method to get a callback whenever the primary screen changes (meaning for example if monitor 1 was primary screen of the system before now monitor 2 is, thus causing a change of refresh rate in the window), but upon trying it even when the primary screen changed I got no callback, and even when I changed the refresh rate of my monitors the QScreen's refresh rates remained the exact same. That being said I overrode the *nativeEvent()* method of QWindow and used the debugger to see what Qt was doing with the message that the window was receiving. I discovered a switch statement and for the message **WM_DISPLAYCHANGE** (which is the message that gets sent when a monitors refresh rate changes, even though the microsoft documentation says it only gets sent upon a change in display resolution)
Qt jumps to this case:

```cpp
case QtWindows::UnknownEvent:
        return false;
```

I haven't dug much deeper than this but considering the refresh rates of the QScreens remain the same and I get no callback I'd say this message is just not handled anywhere after this switch statement either. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Edit: Here is a minimal reproducible example

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

struct Foo : QObject
{
public slots:

    void refreshRateChangedCallback(qreal refreshRate)
    {
        qDebug() << "Refresh rate of monitor changed! " << refreshRate;
    }
    void primaryScreenChangedCallback(QScreen *screen)
    {
        qDebug() << "Primary screen changed! " << screen->name();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;

    view.setSource(u"qrc:/test/Main.qml"_qs);

    view.show();
    QScreen *primaryScreen = view.screen();
    Foo *test = new Foo;

    QObject::connect(primaryScreen,
                     &QScreen::refreshRateChanged,
                     test,
                     &Foo::refreshRateChangedCallback);
    QObject::connect(&app,
                     &QGuiApplication::primaryScreenChanged,
                     test,
                     &Foo::primaryScreenChangedCallback);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Upon running this code even if the refresh rate on my monitor is changed *refreshRateChangedCallback()* doesn't get called, neither does *primaryScreenChangedCallback()* get called upon a switch of the primary screen of the system.

```
My Qt version is 6.6.0 compiled with MSVC 2019 
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎7/‎2/‎2023
OS build    19045.3930
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0
```

I don't think that I have touched the system environment in a way significant to this issue, but if I can provide something more that could help, I will.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your explanation, but I'm under the impression that you may be misunderstanding the meaning of "primary screen" and the related changed signal. The primary screen is the default screen in which any new window is (probably) being shown the first time, and is set for the system; the `primaryScreenChanged` is only emitted when *another* screen has been set as primary for the system (possibly by user action, for example if the primary screen was physically disconnected), but that has nothing to do with changes *of* the primary screen.

Comment: @musicamante I wouldn't exactly put my explanation in the hall of fame, but you didn't misunderstand. That's exactly what I am talking about: neither a change of the primary screen of the system is detected(meaning another monitor becoming the primary one), nor a change in the refresh rate of any monitor of the system. _primaryScreenChanged()_ doesn't get called when the primary screen of the system changes. (separately from that) I also tried to connect to QScreen's _refreshRateChanged(qreal refreshRate)_ signal but that doesn't fire as well when I change the refresh rate of the monitor.

Comment: So, *I did* misunderstand :-) I've never used those signals and I don't have a system that allows me to do that right now, but I suggest you to edit your post and provide a valid [mre] to start with. It may be a bug, but we need to ensure that everything you're doing is correct. You should also include more detailed information about your OS and Qt version and any specific customization to the system and environment that may be relevant to the problem.

Comment: @musicamante I edited the question with an example and some system information. If there's anything else I should add that could be of help please do tell, thanks.